# R function can't be found

Tags: r, function, rstudio, environment

I have an R script where I use the following code:

```
gspcRets = diff( log( Cl( qxts ) ) )
```

When i run the script from RStudio everything works fine.However,when i run the script from Terminal with the command:

```
RScript my_script.R
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in Cl(qxts) : could not find function "Cl"
```

My script loads all the necessary libraries.I assume it has something to do with the fact that my system needs some kind of access to the RStudio environment.Any ideas?

Comment: Is this function `Cl` part of "quantmod" package?

Comment: Can you add your script? Can try `<Cl_package_name>::Cl` in the script.

Comment: You re totally right!I forgot to include the "quantmod" package.It works now.I still have one question though.In RStudio,I use the: rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) command to clear all the environment's variables.The script still works there because i loaded the quantmod package previously.This command isnt it supposed to clear the packages,too?

Comment: No it does not, it only cleans `Global Environment`

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to load the "quantmod" package.An RStudio's active session continues to use the packages that have been loaded previously even after i used the command:

```
 rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
```